# How to compare features and classifiers which achieve perfect accuracy?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, feature-selection

So I'm looking to compare different combinations of features and classifiers. But I'm getting a lot of combinations that achieve 100% cross validation accuracy. I'm trying to figure out how I would compare the usefulness of each combination.

For example I can both train an SVM using Features 1, 10, 15 to get 100% accuracy. But at the same time I can train a logistic regression classifier only using Feature 7 to get 100% accuracy. Also this is a binary classification problem.